# Best ways to lock functions with authentication in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, authentication, permissions

I've read about AuthGuard in Angular but it's highly based on routes, however the application I'm working on use only one route and page.

Authentication would be needed to disable functionalities or restrict access to modal windows like a window for editing.

Since I don't use more than one route I'm courious if there is a better solution for this than ngIf everything based on the url (and use multiple url for one page...).

Answer (score 0):

@atani You can disable the page access by using CanActivate interface
or by writing a service file with high functionality for making conditions work
u can go through this documentation:https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate